# Problema con !pip install mmseg

Tags: python, google-colab, pytorch

Estoy intentando utilizar un modelo de hugging face para resolver un problema propio. Para ello lo estoy corriendo desde google colab pero tengo este problema cuando intento instalar la dependencia mmseg.

Muestra el siguiente error:

```
Collecting mmseg
  Downloading mmseg-1.3.0.tar.gz (817 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 817.4/817.4 kB 14.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 0):

Por contexto (hugging face y supongo que PyTorch) estoy bastante seguro  que el paquete que realmente quieres instalar es [mmsegmentation](https://github.com/open-mmlab/mmsegmentation) (de open-mmlab).

Aunque se importa con el nombre que usas para intentar instalarlo (por ejemplo, `import mmseg`) ese no es su nombre en PyPI. En PyPI *mmseg* se refiere a [otro paquete](https://pypi.org/project/mmseg/) (bastante desactualizado ademas, por lo que es de esperar que no funcione con versiones recientes de Python/pip), debes usar:

```
!pip install mmsegmentation
```

Es recomendable seguir las [instrucciones de instalación](https://github.com/open-mmlab/mmsegmentation/blob/main/docs/en/get_started.md#installation) del propio paquete en su repo en GitHub.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tu respuesta. from mmcv import Config
from mmseg.models import build_segmentor
from mmseg.datasets.pipelines import Compose, LoadImageFromFile
from mmseg.apis import init_segmentor
from model_inference import inference_segmentor, process_test_pipeline
from huggingface_hub import hf_hub_download
import matplotlib
from torch import nn. De esta forma importan el paquete en el código. De ahí mi duda. Pruebo la solución que em recomiendas. Nuevamente muchas gracias!!!

Comment: from mmseg.datasets import Compose, LoadImageFromFile
ahora está este otro problema  ----------------------------------------------------
      2 from mmseg.models import build_segmentor
----> 3 from mmseg.datasets import Compose, LoadImageFromFile
      4 from mmseg.apis import init_segmentor
      5 from model_inference import inference_segmentor, process_test_pipeline
ImportError: cannot import name 'Compose' from 'mmseg.datasets' (/content/mmsegmentation/mmseg/datasets/__init__.py)